# Atlassian Confluence Image not Deployed at the OpenShift Sandbox

Tags: openshift, confluence

I attempted to deploy a Confluence Atlassian instance at the OpenShift Sandbox from the following repository:
https://github.com/cptactionhank/docker-atlassian-confluence

An image / build strategy has been detected, but the POD remains autoscaled to zero.
Do you think it would be possible to give me some help with this topic please ?

[image: Topology]

I gave it a try at this repository as well:
https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-image-atlassian-confluence/tree/main

It appears that these was one of the confluence builds that was successful, but the URL does not open :

[image: EugenMayer_Confluence_Instance]

(I am assuming that I must do some configurations, but I am not 100% sure)

In case anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.
Thank you very much!